# NuGet and nUnit automation

Tags: nunit, nuget

I have a VS project and in the project properties under the Debug tab I set:
  Start External Program:  D:\SolutionName\packages\NUnit.2.5.10.11092\tools\nunit.exe
  Command Arguments:   projectname.dll

This lets me start nUnit and run the nunits tests dll and when I start debugging the project.

Is there a better way?  We use TFS and not everyone installs the solution to d: and the version number in the path where NuGet installs it changes periodically.

Was hoping to some how grab the text of the nunit.exe path from the path in the VS: Project : References section that was placed there by NuGet.  This way I wouldn't have to change it for nUnit version changes and other TFS users wouldn't have to change it either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at this:
http://lostechies.com/joshuaflanagan/2011/06/24/how-to-use-a-tool-installed-by-nuget-in-your-build-scripts/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using NUnit in NuGet, then the runner will be in `packages\NUnit(version)\`, so you could probably use `$(SolutionDir)packages\NUnit(blah)` in the External Program command to run the version pulled from the NuGet package.

Answer (score 0):

As Danny mentioned, install it to a relative (to your source code) tools folder via NuGet, ie
./tools/nuget.exe install Nunit.Runners -o ./tools

Then in your project configuration, just use the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.  After a great deal of searching I found this question: [Get NuGet package folder in MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705650/get-nuget-package-folder-in-msbuild)

Basically, you can create a project item containing a sort-of "wildcard" in the path name in place of the specific version number and then tell MSBuild to retrieve the relative path directory.