# Get NuGet package folder in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, build-automation, nuget, nuget-package

I want to call executable tools like NUnit which I manage via NuGet in MSBuild:

```
<Target Name="Test">
  <CreateItem Include="$(BuildCompileDirectory)\*.Tests.*dll">
    <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="TestAssemblies" />
  </CreateItem>
  <NUnit
    Assemblies="@(TestAssemblies)"
    ToolPath="$(PackagesDirectory)\NUnit.2.5.10.11092\tools"
    WorkingDirectory="$(BuildCompileDirectory)"
    OutputXmlFile="$(BuildDirectory)\$(SolutionName).Tests.xml" />
</Target>
```

The problem is that the folder of a NuGet packages is containing the version number of the package. For instance `nunit-console.exe` is in the folder `packages\NUnit.2.5.10.11092\tools`. If I update the NUnit package this path will change and I have to update my MSBuild script. That isn't acceptable.

MSBuild doesn't allow Wildcards in directories, so this isn't working:

```
ToolPath="$(PackagesDirectory)\NUnit.*\tools"
```

How can I call tools in MSBuild without having to update my build script whenever I update a NuGet package?

Comment: In MsBuild 15 you can use `PackageReference` with `GeneratePathProperty="true"`. See https://www.patriksvensson.se/2019/09/how-to-find-a-nuget-package-path-from-msbuild .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [MSBuild Transforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-transforms?view=vs-2019) to get the relative directory of a specific tool:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <NunitPackage Include="$(PackagesDirectory)\NUnit.*\tools\nunit-console.exe"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Test">
  <CreateItem Include="$(BuildCompileDirectory)\*.Tests.*dll">
    <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="TestAssemblies" />
  </CreateItem>
  <NUnit
    Assemblies="@(TestAssemblies)"
    ToolPath="@(NunitPackage->'%(relativedir)')"
    WorkingDirectory="$(BuildCompileDirectory)"
    OutputXmlFile="$(BuildDirectory)\$(SolutionName).Tests.xml" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Is "$(PackagesDirectory)" an item you've defined yourself?

Comment: @DavidTchepak Yes, it is.

Comment: What if solution is big and contains multiple versions of the same package (used by different projects)? In that case you may reference the wrong version (i.e. not the one which is specified in your project's "packages.config" file.

Comment: You can also use the `$(NuGetPackageRoot)` macro. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57048513/1885735

Answer (score 3):

The comment of [Mike Rosoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8278466/mike-rosoft) links to [Patrik Svensson his blog](https://www.patriksvensson.se/2019/09/how-to-find-a-nuget-package-path-from-msbuild) post and it helped me as follows:

- Add `GeneratePathProperty="true"` to `PackageReference` of the NuGet package you want to have the location of.
- Use it as `$(PkgPackage_Name)` whereby the dots are replaced by an underscore. Note the **Pkg** prefix.

This example forces Nswag to use the 32 bit dotnet.exe by overwriting the existing `NSwagExe_Net60` property. This was necessary on an x86 project.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <NSwagExe_Net60>"$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\dotnet\dotnet.exe" "$(PkgNSwag_MSBuild)\tools\Net60\dotnet-nswag.dll"</NSwagExe_Net60>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.MSBuild" Version="13.16.1" GeneratePathProperty="true">
  </ItemGroup>
```