# MSBuild Macro for NuGet package directory

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I'm working on a NuGet package that adds a step to the build process by using a `.targets` file.

I need to reference other files from my NuGet package in order to complete the build successfully.

In the past, I've used `$(SolutionDir)packages\MyPackage` and all has worked fine.

However, I was just playing around with the VS 2017 RC, and I noticed that my package was installed in the global NuGet package directory, not in the solution folder.

Is there some macro that I can use from MSBuild, that contains the path for the NuGet `packages` folder? It is a requirement that I maintain compatibility with VS2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alternative method that create a NuGet.Config file in the root of the \Solutions\ folder to set the package repositoryPath of VS 2017 RC, add to NuGet.Config the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>  
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="$\..\Packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

For the repositoryPath setting, you can specify an absolute path or relative path (recommended) using the $ token. The $ token is based on where the NuGet.Config is located. In this case, you package will install in `$(SolutionDir)packages\` folder, you can used `$(SolutionDir)packages\MyPackage` for Visual Studio 2017 RC. It`s also maintain compatibility with VS2012.

Comment: I guess this is for old-style project references, where the packages directory is in the solution folder -- not for new-style project references where the packages directory is in [%userprofile%\.nuget\packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-a-build?view=vs-2022)

Answer (score 35):

The `$(NuGetPackageRoot)` macro points to the package root.

Comment: This doesnt show up in the "Macros<<" dialog list in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @AndrewRobinson Many macros aren't in that list